# Computing the sum of $\log^2(\text{eigenvalues})$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Is there a method to find $$\sum_{\{\lambda \text{ is an eigenvalue}\}} \log^2(\lambda)$$
of a symmetric matrix without explicitly calculating the eigenvalues?

Comment: I edit your post. Please make sure it's what you meant.

Comment: Using the [matrix logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm_of_a_matrix), it suffices to compute 
$$
\operatorname{tr}(\log^2(A))
$$
however, computing the matrix logarithm without finding eigenvalues typically requires a careful treatment of the appropriate power-series definition.

Comment: I guess you are thinking the following: let us say A' is the diagonal matrix related to A such that A=S^(-1) A' S. Then \log(A) = \log(S^(-1) A' S). But this is equal to \log(S^(-1) S) +\log(A') iff A' and S commute.  Hence your result will hold only in that case.

Comment: @Joe it is generally true that $\log(S^{-1}A'S) = S^{-1}\log(A')S$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom can you please provide me a proof of the claim?

Comment: @Joe it can be proven using either the power-series definition of a log or the fact that $e^{S^{-1}XS} = S^{-1}e^XS$.

Answer (score 3):

We need to deal with positive definite real symmetric matrices, otherwise $\log^2(\lambda)$ for $\lambda\in\text{Spec}(M)$ might be undefined. We may notice that for any $k\in\mathbb{N}$ the identity
$$ \sum_{\lambda\in\text{Spec}(M)}\lambda^k = \text{Tr}(M^k) $$
holds as a consequence of the Hamilton-Cayley theorem. We have
$$ \log^2(1-x)=\sum_{n\geq 2}\frac{2 H_{n-1}}{n}\,x^n,\qquad H_n=\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\ldots+\frac{1}{n} $$
for any $x\in(-1,1)$, hence by assuming that the spectral radius of $M$ is less than $2$ we have
$$ \sum_{\lambda\in\text{Spec}(M)}\log^2(\lambda) = \text{Tr}\sum_{n\geq 2}\frac{2H_{n-1}}{n}(I-M)^n. $$