# $\sum(\log^2(root))$ of an nth order polynomial.

Tags: polynomials, roots

Is there an approach to find the $\sum_{over all roots}(\log^2(root))$ of an nth order polynomial of the form

$a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+.......+a_0$; in terms of the coefficients $a_n$, $a_{n-1}$, $a_{n-2}$,.....,$a_{0}$ (i.e., without explicitly computing the roots and then taking Log and squaring and summing up) ?

Comment: I assume by $\log^2(r)$ you mean $\log(r)^2$ and not the base $2$ log?

Comment: Also, you can't always take the log of a root; what if they are negative?

Comment: @vrugtehagel I mean $(log(r))^2$. Assume all roots are positive.

Answer (score 4):

[You already asked a similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2680598/computing-the-sum-of-log2-texteigenvalues) and you are going to receive a similar answer.
Assuming that all the roots of the given polynomial lie in the ball $\|z-1\|<1$,
$$ \log^2(1+z) = \sum_{n\geq 2}\frac{2H_{n-1}}{n}(-1)^n z^n $$
leads to
$$ \sum_{\zeta}\log^2(\zeta) = \sum_{n\geq 2}\frac{2H_{n-1}}{n}(-1)^n\!\!\!\underbrace{\sum_{\zeta}(\zeta-1)^n}_{\substack{\text{only depends on}\\\text{the coefficients of p.}}}\!\!\!. $$

Comment: can you give me an expression in terms of the coefficients for the expression $\sum_{root}(root-1)^n$ ? It seems to be a complicated expression. Thanks

Comment: @Joe: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities allow to derive $p_k$ (power sums) from $e_k$ (coefficients).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a stantard way of doing that. However, if you replace $\log^2(root)$ by $\log(root)$ you can do the following
$$\sum_{r,P(r)=0}log(r)=log(\mbox{product of roots})= \log a_0,$$

That is assuming all logs are defined. An approach to your problem would be to find a functional property verified by $\log^2$ and see if it helps, but I'm a bit skeptic.

UPDATE: see the other clever answer.

Comment: Thanks. I was aware of this i.e., the sum of log instead of $log^2$